# Why am I getting different outputs for the (seemingly) same code?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm trying to understand why these two examples are giving me different outputs.

Example1:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = []
for l in list1:
    list2.append(l)
print list2

#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Example2:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = []
list2.append(l for l in list1)
print list2

#[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x10379ecd0>]
```

I've tried putting list() or tuple() after the append in the second example, but it's giving me one single element in the new list as opposed to 5 different ones.

```
list2.append(tuple(l for l in list1))

#[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
```

Would there be a way for me to get same same output from Example1 using just one line for the for loop?

I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4):

You need `extend` instead of `append` for the second example

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = []
list2.extend(l for l in list1)  # or just list2.extend(list1)
print list2
```

If all you want to do is copy `list1` then

```
list2 = list1[:]
```

or

```
list2 = list(list1)
```

will do it

Answer (score 3):

`(l for l in list1)` is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression). It explicitly returns a generator, which is essentially a memory-saving iterator (think a list, but with each element returned on the fly, rather than stored all in memory). The key to realising it is a generator expression is in noting that the expression is surrrounded by `(` and `)`.

In `list2.append(l for l in list1)`, you have appended a *single* generator to the empty list. You can still get all the elements you want by doing `for element in list2[0]`, but it is not the same thing.

However, in doing

```
for l in list1:
   list2.append(l)
```

no such generator expressions are encountered. At every iteration - every run of the loop - `l`, an element, is appended to the end. Hence why this works the way you think.

---

If you want to get your `list2` using something similar to the generator expression, you want to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead:

```
list2 = [l for l in list1]
```

Note that the difference between the structure of a list comprehension and a generator expression is simply the presence of square brackets `[`,`]` rather than parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use append in the second example. Instead you want

```
list2 = [l for l in list1]
```

There are easier ways to copy a list, but this is the one that most closely matches what you're going for in Example 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the nested list then you may simply use :

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = []
[list2.append(l) for l in list1]
```